# Web-based Usenet newsreader beside Google Groups?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've been using various newsreaders for years to follow Usenet groups, but I would now appreciate to not be tied to a particular computer or platform. Note that I'm not ready to pay a monthly subscription to read the few text-only groups I'm interested in.

Is there any solution, beside [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/), to read Usenet groups (and post to them) from any computer (to either use online or install on my own server)?  I am looking for something that is closer to a newsreader, with scores, mark-thread-as-read, ignore-thread, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the [Open-News-Network?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-News-Network_e.V.) They have [Webnewsreaders.](http://open-news-network.org/index.php/WebNews) Not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I registered on ONN, and will hopefully be able to try it soon...

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good fit for your requirements, but I follow some groups like comp.python which are mirrored to email, and sometimes I read those at http://news.gmane.org/. I don't think they have everything, but depending on what you read it might be an option.